# Рисование imgui вне windows окна

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, imgui

Я использую glfw3 и создаю окно, в котором рисую imgui интерфейс.
Я хочу сделать так, чтоб imgui окно рисовалось просто на экране, а не в windows окне.
Можно как то сделать чтоб не было видно заголовка окна(с тремя кнопками) или рисовать без окна вовсе?

Comment: Без окна рисовать нельзя, но можно рисовать без всякого оконного обрамления.

Comment: Вероятно вам нужна функция [glfwWindowHint](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3.2/window_guide.html#window_hints) / `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE)`